# RSS Feeds not working in Chrome/ok in IE and Firefox

Tags: rss

I have problems with the RSS feed not functioning properly in Chrome. When clicking on the RSS icon in top header or bottom of [this page](http://healthynaturallyclub.com/), I get strange page message.

I usually put all urls through 'Social profiles', dashboard, 'my themes' but in this case, it does not offer that option. The template is Hades, themeforest. Any ideas where I can input the rss url so that the feed will work.

The rss feed in sidebar works too in all browsers.

Comment: http://bit.ly/ZNuvHq   It works in the sidebar, but not on top, when clicking the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two different links. In the header there is http://healthynaturallyclub.com/?feed=rss2, while in the sidebar there is http://feeds.feedburner.com/HealthyNaturallyClub.

Why is that? Obviously because the underlying code is different. Just replace the rss2 link with the one from FeedBurner (if this feed is actually the one you want to provide) and you should be fine.

**// Edit**

Check your `sidebar.php` (or whatever file your sidebar is contained in) for the code that is being used there for the feed.

You found the right lines in your `header.php` but it seems, the function is either not the one that is being called in the sidebar, or the option `pp_feedburner_id` is different from when it is fetched in the sidebar.

If you want to *hardcode* the link, you have to remove the lines 313-318 and 321-323 (or put a hash # before 314, 316, 317 and 322) and replace `<?php echo $pp_feedburner_id; ?>` with `http://feeds.feedburner.com/HealthyNaturallyClub`.

Comment: Where do I change the "http://healthynaturallyclub.com/?feed=rss2", what dir/file?

Comment: In the file `header.php`. Search for `rss` and adapt the link to your needs.

Comment: Hi...sorry to bug you...this is the only rss code i found in the header file. http://bit.ly/WMs8Iu  Where do I input that url? Thank you much..I'm still learning :)

Comment: See updated answer.